# Buscar aniversariantes do mês

Tags: mysql, cakephp-2

Gostaria de fazer um condição onde só exiba os aniversariantes do mês. Meu controller ficou assim:

```
public function index()
{
    $ultimoDia = date("t", mktime(0,0,0,date('m'),'01',date('Y')));
    $condicoes['order'] = array('Funcionario.NomFun' => 'ASC');
    $condicoes['conditions'] = array(
        'Funcionario.SitAfa <>' => 7,
        'Funcionario.datNasc >=' => date("m").'-01',
        'Funcionario.datNasc <=' => date("Y-m").'-'.$ultimoDia
    );
    $condicoes['limit'] = 60;
    var_dump($condicoes['conditions']);
    $this->paginate = $condicoes;
    $this->set('aniversariantes', $this->paginate());
}
```

Mas não funciona ele nao lista nada pois a string que ele retorna é:

```
'Funcionario.datNasc >=' => string '09-01' (length=5)
'Funcionario.datNasc <=' => string '2015-09-30' (length=10)
```

e a tabela `datNasc` retorna a data do funcionário completa ex: string '2015-09-18'.

Answer (score 1):

Experimente fazer a condição somente com o mês, assim:

```
$condicoes['conditions'] = array(
    "Funcionario.SitAfa <>" => 7,
    "DATE_FORMAT(Funcionario.datNasc, '%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%m')"
);
```

Comment: Cara perfeito, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta assim:

```
public function index(){
    $ultimoDia = date("t", mktime(0,0,0,date('m'),'01',date('Y')));
    $condicoes['order'] = array('Funcionario.NomFun' => 'ASC');
    $condicoes['conditions'] = array(
        'month(Funcionario.datNasc) =' => date("m"),
    );
    $condicoes['limit'] = 60;
    var_dump($condicoes['conditions']);
    $this->paginate = $condicoes;
    $this->set('aniversariantes', $this->paginate());
}
```